# How to keep special symbols like "(" "," and "#" in tokens in R?

Tags: r, data-mining, tokenize

I'm dealing with a text file that has words like "c#", "c++", and ".net" from jobs ads. When I convert it into tokens, the "#" , "++", and the dot are removed. How can I keep them in the resulting tokens? Here is my code:

```
unnest_tokens(word,REQUIREMENTS, token = "words",to_lower=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the argument `token = "words"`, which splits on non-word characters (presumably using the regex `\\W+`).  This function throws away the delimiters, so in order to keep those characters, you will have to use some other argument than `"words"`.  You might want to define your own splitting regex with `token = "regex"` and something like this:

```
unnest_tokens(word,
              REQUIREMENTS,
              token = "regex",
              to_lower = TRUE,
              pattern = "\\s+") # split on whitespace rather than non-word elements
```

This way, [you can define whatever regex you need](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) to customize how the text is tokenized.